# Counting rows where a timestamp is less than 24 hours old

Tags: mysql, timestamp

For the query below, how could I count the number of rows where `datesent` is less than 24 hours old?  (The field `datesent` is a timestamp).

Thanks in advance,

John

```
  $message = "SELECT datesent, recipient
               FROM privatemessage 
              WHERE recipient = '$u'";


  $messager = mysql_query($message);

$messagearray = array();
```

Comment: i removed the `css` tag as it had nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 61):

Use:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
  FROM PRIVATEMESSAGE pm
 WHERE pm.datesent >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Comment: This is the only answer that passes the correct value into the first parameter of DATE_SUB

Comment: Thanks... this looks promising.  But I'm having trouble actually echoing out the result to see if it works.  How could I echo the total?

Comment: @John: I updated to define a column alias -- the "cnt" is what you'd reference in PHP to get the value for the column.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [DATE_SUB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub) function.  Subtract one day from the current date in the where clause.

Something like

```
DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

EDIT: changed CURTIME() to NOW()

Comment: `CURTIME` only returns the time, not date and time.

Comment: CURTIME just returns the current time, nothing to do with the current date.  You would want to pass NOW() instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
$message="select count(1)
from privatemessage
where datesent>=date_sub(now(), 24 hours)
and recipient='$u'"
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

Comment: This will return a count of every row, because it's comparing that the existing value is greater or equal to the same value, after subtracting 24 hours from it...  Performing a function on a column in the table also means an index, if one existed, couldn't be used for the operation.

Comment: Right you are.  Sorry, I don't use MySQL, so I didn't have the chance to test the solution before posting it.

Comment: The unit is HOUR (singular), not HOURS. See the link that you already provided: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

Answer (score 2):

I see this is a old one though for anybody that gets here trough an online search later on, I would like to clarify that the question is about a timestamp, not datetime. I needed a count based on timestamp. Easy fix is to convert the datetime to unix_timestamp. Tested on MySQL 5.7

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM PRIVATEMESSAGE pm
WHERE pm.datesent >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```